# Bitwise arithmetic on an integer return value

Tags: c++, integer, return-value, bitwise-operators

Here we have a function fire() which accepts two arguments:

- A capital letter (char) in the range of 'A' .. 'A'+BS_GRID_ROWS-1 that indicates the row in your grid to attack.
- An integer (int) in the range of 1 .. BS_GRID_COLS that indicates the column of your grid to attack.

The return code will be:

- 0 if there is only open water.
- The bit BS_SHIP_HIT will be set, or both BS_SHIP_HIT and BS_SHIP_SANK will be set. In addition, the ship that was hit will be indicated in the lowest four bits of the return code. You may use BS_SHIP_MASK to help extract the number for the ship type.

semi-pseudocode interpretation:

```
//r is A ... (A + BS_GRID_ROWS - 1)
//c is 1 ... BS_GRID_COLS

fire(char r, int c) {
    //some set of commands

    if(miss) {
        return 0;
    else if(sink) {
        return hit + sunk + size;
    else if(hit) {
        return hit;
    else {
        return miss;
    }
}
```

I am uncertain of exactly how I might go about extracting these individual values (hit, sunk, size) from the return value.

The actual `.h` file and it's relevant `const` values are seen here:

```
#ifndef BATTLESHIP
#define BATTLESHIP
const int BS_SHIP_HIT  = 0x10;  // Ship is hit, or
const int BS_SHIP_SANK = 0x20; // sank (must also | BS_SHIP_HIT)
const int BS_CARRIER   = 1;
const int BS_BATTLESHIP= 2;
const int BS_CRUISER   = 3;
const int BS_DESTROYER = 4;
const int BS_SUBMARINE = 5;
const int BS_SHIP_COUNT = 5;
const int BS_SHIP_MASK = 0x0F;
const int BS_CARRIER_SIZE   = 5;
const int BS_BATTLESHIP_SIZE= 4;
const int BS_CRUISER_SIZE   = 3;
const int BS_DESTROYER_SIZE = 2;
const int BS_SUBMARINE_SIZE = 3;
const int BS_MODE_NEW_GAME   = 1;
const int BS_MODE_CONTINUE_GAME = 2;
const int BS_GRID_ROWS = 10; // letters A to J
const int BS_GRID_COLS = 10; // numbers 1 to 10
const int MaxPlayerCount = 65; // Maximum size for following arrays
extern int userIncoming(char, int);
extern int userBattle(int, int);
extern int incomingStub(char, int);
extern int battleStub(int, int);
extern int (*fire[])(char, int);
extern int (*battleship[])(int, int);
extern char const *playerName[];
#endif
```

Comment: Try the bitwise AND operator `&`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not quite certain of how it works. Could you explain it a little for me?

Comment: I'd recommend to return a struct containing bools (or pass the address of or a reference to one as a parameter if you are concerned about speed). Much clearer than bit fiddling (why would anybody do that? You end up writing macros for it anyway!), and not limited to a certain number of states. Unless `fire()`'s specification is a given ;-).

Comment: Bit-fiddling like this is usually done nowadays in special cases, such as extremely low memory. If you just want to make a battleship game, I would use enum, class etc other high-level techniques.

Comment: All capitals are by convention reserved for macros. Instead of prefixing everything with BS, it should be more C++ to put them in a namespace.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I'd do the same, but I'm *given* the function. I was unfamiliar with the bitwise `&` operator, but our good friend Joachim helped clear that up for me. I just wish I didn't have to get down-vote bombed for a fairly genuine question. What is SO for, after all?

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't disagree. This is given, however. I am working with what my professor gives me. I've never worked with bitwise operators, so that was my confusion.

Comment: The downvotes (not from me, fwiw) are probably because the subject (binary representation of ints and bitwise operations on them) is so basic that it is expected that students look it up on their own. The question is just *uninteresting*  and the downvotes are a warning to others to not waste their time. My guess is actually that it was presented in class, wasn't it? Joachim was nice, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
int result = fire(r, c);
if (result & BS_SHIP_HIT)
{
    std::cout << "Ship of size " << result & BS_SHIP_MASK << " hit\n";
}
```

If the `BS_SHIP_HIT` bit is set in `result`, the the result of `result & BIT_SHIP_HIT` will be equal to `BS_SHIP_HIT` otherwise the result will be zero (which is equivalent to false).

The result of `result & BS_SHIP_MASK` will be the low four bits in `result`.

---

Or lets look at it using the actual bits:

`BS_SHIP_HIT` is equal to the binary value `00010000` and `BS_SHIT_MASK` equal `00001111`. Lets assume that `fire` returns `00010101` (`BS_SHIP_HIT` set and size 5), then the `if` condition will be

```
  00010000
& 00010101
----------
= 00010000
```

Then for the printing, the expression will be

```
  00010101
& 00001111
----------
= 00000101
```